# Validate input field (inside directive) on form submit (outside) in angular

Tags: angularjs

I created directive my-input which outputs an input based on the attributes supplied to directive. And the rendered input also needs to be validate and display error in case of invalid input. The directive is working absolutely fine but the problem is that I am not able to test those inputs on form submit.

Suppose when the page loads and without doing anything if I click on submit then nothing happens. I want the error to be display and the text box to become highlight for the error.

You can see the live version here: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E89BjKbHGLYt5u4RdTLi?p=preview)

```
[plnkr]: https://plnkr.co/edit/E89BjKbHGLYt5u4RdTLi?p=preview
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fieldset for all form input fields its perfect disables all input until a response.

```js
<fieldset ng-disabled="vm.isSaving">
        <md-input-container class="md-block mt20">
            <md-icon tabindex="-1" md-svg-src="../../images/materialIcons/ic_person_24px.svg" class="name ng-isolate-scope"></md-icon>
            <input ng-model="vm.userName" id="txtUserName" type="text" placeholder="Username (required)" ng-required="true">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <md-icon tabindex="-1" md-svg-src="../../images/materialIcons/ic_email_24px.svg" class="email"></md-icon>
            <input ng-model="vm.emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email (required)" ng-required="true">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <md-icon tabindex="-1" md-svg-src="../../images/materialIcons/ic_email_24px.svg" class="email"></md-icon>
            <input ng-model="vm.retypeEmailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Retype Your Email (required)" ng-required="true">
        </md-input-container>
        <p class="fb">YOUR PASSWORD WILL BE EMAILED</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success w200" data-ng-click="vm.register($event)">Create Account</button>
    </fieldset>
```

e.g.
 onclick function set vm.isSaving = true; if error set vm.isSaving = false; and then I use angular material alert. I call it with one line

```js
showAlert('Unable to register', 'Email Address already registered - request password recovery', ev);
```

see here [Reusable Angular Material Dialog and Toast for Information Helper and Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999959/reusable-angular-material-dialog-and-toast-for-information-helper-and-alert)